# Track data changes with trigger and table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, azure

At the moment, we track data changes in the following manner:

Create a duplicate table of the table we're tracking, with a few extra columns:

So, the main table (An example)

```
CREATE TABLE person
(
   personId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   personName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   personAge INT NOT NULL,
   CreateUserID INT NOT NULL,
   CreateDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
   UpdateUserID INT NULL,
   UpdateDate DATETIME NULL
)
```

Then, the table to hold the updates.

```
CREATE TABLE person_history
(
   person_history_id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   actionType CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
   personId INT NOT NULL,
   personName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   personAge INT NOT NULL,
   CreateUserID INT NOT NULL,
   CreateDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
   UpdateUserID INT NULL,
   UpdateDate DATETIME NULL
)
```

We then create a trigger on the main table for Updates, and a trigger for Inserts.

If it's an update, the ActionType is U, and if it's an insert, it's an I. And we then just copy all the columns into the History table.

This runs on SQL server 2008 R2, and also, a version runs on Azure.

We've been asked by the admins, NOT to use SQL Server's Change Tracking. I'm not even sure change tracking is automatically available in Azure. I have never used it, but ... would it be worth investigating, and trying to sell the the Admins?

Because, I need to be able to create lines for history display to show:

```
[User] inserted a new person on [Date]. 
[User] change the Age from 27 to 29 on the [Date] 
[User] change the Age from 29 to 32 and the Name from James to Peter on the [Date]
```

Is using a trigger and a history table a suitable and recommended way, or would using change tracking be an option? (2008 R2 and Azure)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not Change Tracking (CT), but Change Data Capture (CDC) and yes, [Azure does support it](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2976.how-to-enable-sql-azure-change-tracking.aspx). Change Tracking simply tells you that a row has changed. It doesn't tell you which column changed or what the old and new values are.

A trigger is invoke synchronously, meaning all DML statements (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`) must wait for the trigger to complete. CDC works off the SQL Server Log. There is a (configurable) time delay before it scans the log but it doesn't block the DML statements.

Many developers like the trigger method because it means less to manage for them and it is easy to understand. If that table has large numbers of inserts/updates/deletes, use CDC. Otherwise, a trigger is enough.